# delete records in sqlite

Tags: sqlite

There is a table named commonprofit,three fields :name ,date,profit.
`select  name,max(date)   from commonprofit  group  by name`
the command can get many records which the date is max by the group `name`,
now i want to delete every record which was selected by the command,why i can't do that as the following:

```
drop from commonprofit where date in (select  name,max(date)   from commonprofit  group  by name);

delete  from commonprofit where date=max(date)  group  by name;

delete from commonprofit where date in (select  name,max(date)   from commonprofit  group  by name);
```

neither of them can do.

the primitive data is :

```
name  date  profit
1   2011/12 42359
1   2010/12 32863
1   2009/12 24293
1   2008/12 16436
1   2007/12 15442
2   2011/12 91634
2   2010/12 58410
2   2009/12 50668
2   2008/12 54297
3   2009/12 12352
3   2008/12 12352
3   2007/12 14226
```

what i want to delete is :

```
name    date    profit
1       2011/12 42359
2       2011/12 91634
3       2009/12 12352
```

what i want to get is :

```
name  date  profit
1   2010/12 32863
1   2009/12 24293
1   2008/12 16436
1   2007/12 15442
2   2010/12 58410
2   2009/12 50668
2   2008/12 54297
3   2008/12 12352
3   2007/12 14226
```

how can i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to delete records like this is by identifying them with a single unique column.
You did not show a primary key, so I'm using the `rowid`.
`IN` requires a subquery with a single column, so we have to use an extra indirection:

```
DELETE FROM commonprofit
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid
                FROM (SELECT rowid,
                             MAX(date)
                      FROM commonprofit
                      GROUP BY name))
```

Answer (score -1):

You should use `delete` and not `drop`

The `drop` command is for deleting entire tables and thier schema definitions. Use `delete` to delete rows from a table.

Comment: it can't run ,SQLiteManager: Likely SQL syntax error:   delete from commonprofit where date in (select  name,max(date)   from commonprofit  group  by name); [ only a single result allowed for a SELECT that is part of an expression ]
Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [mozIStorageConnection.createStatement]

Comment: This command (if it worked) would also delete records with the same `date` in other `name` groups.

Comment: OOps -- spotted the "DROP" rather than "DELETE" but didnt check the rest of his logic -- will edit.